# How do create a sample users in Azure to test OpenID

Tags: azure, openid-connect

I have a web application that is capable of authenticating via OpenID.

I want to be able to test it with Azure as an OpenID provider using some fake users as a sample set. Is there a free way of doing this? I do have a visual studio subscription if it helps.

Futher note: I did actually manage to set this up before, but I've forgotten exactly how. All my users where under a domain like xxxxx.onmicrosoft.com. Since then everything has moved to Entra.

Looking for some guidance.

Comment: Could you confirm whether your requirement is to create sample set of users in Microsoft Entra ID via PowerShell or Portal?

Comment: Yes I was able to solve the issue by following this link
https://medium.com/@antoniosql/how-to-get-a-microsoft-365-demo-tenant-8381d712b305

Answer (score 0):

To create **sample set** of users in Microsoft Entra ID, you can make use of **`Bulk create`** option and Download CSV template in Azure Portal like this:

[image]

Now, open the downloaded CSV and add sample user's properties like **Name**, **User principal name**, **Initial password** and **Block sign in (Yes/No)**:

[image]

Now, upload this CSV file on **Bulk create users** page of Azure Portal like this:

[image]

When I checked the same in Portal after few minutes, sample set of users **created** successfully as below:

[image]

Alternatively, you can join **Microsoft 365 Developer** Program with Microsoft account that creates sample set of 25 users with M365 E5 license as you mentioned in comments.

**Reference:**
[How to get a Microsoft 365 demo tenant | by **Antonio Soto** | Medium](https://medium.com/@antoniosql/how-to-get-a-microsoft-365-demo-tenant-8381d712b305)